# Location clustering in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

I am working on displaying about 40,000 latitude longitude points on a map over Australia, I suspect most points are in towns but don't have data on the towns and would like to be able to cluster the points to get it to a size where I could put pins with totals on a map, to help get a better understanding of the data.

Is there some way to query to get a list of clusters with location of the cluster and count for the point at that cluster?

Comment: Have you considerd using Power BI desktop for this? If you import the data into Power BI and visualize it with a map control. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-map-tips-and-tricks)